# Convert Postman/newman collection request in python

Tags: python, api, scripting, postman, newman

I have a collection of postman requests in JSON format. I need to write a python script that runs this collection and check the return code of all request in the collection. I already see the postman tool for convert request into code, but I need to do this dynamically, because the collection may change in the future. Is there some python package that can help me? Maybe some wrapper for newman/postman?

Answer (score 1):

[Postman newman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/#:%7E:text=Newman%20is%20a%20command%20line,directly%20from%20the%20command%20line.&text=Newman%20maintains%20feature%20parity%20with,the%20collection%20runner%20in%20Postman.) provides a [command line interface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#using-newman-cli) and a [node.js library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#using-newman-as-a-library). You could [invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92395/833960) the command line interface from your python code.

You could also try https://pypi.org/project/postpy2/